# Text value is not being set with input and turns to 'None' in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

M using `<ui:inputtext value="{!f.Text_Value__c}">` under `<aura:iteration>` and this field value is passed from an object's field "Text_Value__c". When page loads it shows correct value fetched from apex. Once I start typing in this input box, it renders but I blur out from this input box, the text becomes "None". I am surprised...in console.log()..it's showing correct value...there is no place in code where I am making this field value as "None".

Source Code:

```
<aura:attribute name="fieldInfo" type="List"></aura:attribute>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.fieldInfo}" var="f" >

<ui:inputText class="form-control" value="{!f.Text_Value__c}"/>
</aura:iteration>



var result   = cmp.get("v.formLevelWrapper");    
var pagelist = result.pageMap;
var currentPage = pagelist[currentPageNumber];        
cmp.set("v.currentPage", currentPage);
cmp.set("v.headermessage", currentPage.thisPage.Label__c);
var flist = currentPage.fieldList;
var cresult= [];
for(var i = 0; i < flist.length; i++){
    var cfield = flist[i];
    cfield.Text_Value__c = flist[i].Text_Value__c;
    cresult.push(cfield);
}
cmp.set("v.fieldInfo", cresult);
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: is f a wrapper attribute?

Comment: Nop, It's a custom object variable...added code..

Comment: Where do you set the fieldInfo attribute ?

Comment: Sorry...updated the code!

Comment: I guess you should replace f with v in Text_Value__c

Comment: @SharpDixit - No because f is the iteration variable